# TcxGRid, Change style of selected row

Tags: tcxgrid

I change the row-colors with OnGetContentStyle, so depending on a value the color of the row is different:

if      ( ARecord.Values[ ViewCol1.Index ] = null  )
and NOT ( ARecord.Values[ ViewCol2.Index  ] = null  )
then
AStyle := StyleRed ;

Now, when the row is selected, this does not work. Is there a way to override the color of the selected row with the same condition?